# Javadoc-annotated source files for OpenGL ES 2.0 methods

Tags: android, opengl-es, gradle, android-studio, javadoc

Is there a javadoc annotated version of the source files for OpenGL ES 2.0? If yes, how can I tell Android Studio (Gradle 0.9) to use those source files instead of the (uncommented) source files in API 19 source.

Reason: I am new to OpenGL ES and all the methods of GLES20 are giving me a headache, as I am never sure which parameter does what, what the method might do and what it may return. Currently I constantly have to look up methods on http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/ and that is not very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

I struggle for this issue recently. Add extra javadoc for Android Studio mainly create a desired `javadoc.jar` and add a reference entries in `jdk.table.xml` configuration file to refer your `javadoc.jar`.

Documentation for GLES is easily to obtain luckily, and create an `javadoc.jar` also without too much pain.

See this project https://github.com/WanghongLin/xjavadoc, following the instruction to install plugin and add GLES2.0 and EGL documentation support for Android Studio.

Or download the final generated [file](https://github.com/WanghongLin/xjavadoc/blob/master/release/android-gles-javadoc.jar) and add reference to it from `jdk.table.xml` manually.